# I am trying to make a login page. However something keeps going wrong - and I don't know what?

Tags: php

I'm new at PHP and I've been following a course on how to make a sign up/login page. I have successfully finished the signup page but the login page is giving me issues. Here is my code for my login.php:

```
<?php
include_once '../resources/session.php';
include_once '../resources/database.php';
include_once '../resources/utilities.php';

if(isset($_POST['loginBtn'])){

    // array to hold errors
    $form_errors = array();

    // validate
    $required_fields = array('username ', 'password ');

    $form_errors = array_merge($form_errors, check_empty_fields($required_fields));

    if(empty($form_errors)){

        // collect form data
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //  check if user exists in the database
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
        $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $statement->execute(array(':username' => $user));

        while($row = $statement->fetch()){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $hashedpassword = $row['password'];
            $username = $row['username'];

            if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("location: dashboard.php");
            }
            else{
                $result ="<p style='padding: 20px; color: red; border: 1px solid gray;'> Invalid username or password</p>";
            }
        }

    }
    else{
        if(count($form_errors) == 1){
            $result = "<p style='color:red;'>There was 1 error in the form</p>";
        }
        else{
            $result = "<p style='color:red;'> There were " .count($form_errors). " errors in the form </p>";
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/indexstyles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <?php if(isset($result)) echo $result; ?>
        <?php if(!empty($form_errors)) echo show_errors($form_errors); ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="" name="username "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" value="" name="password "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input style="float: right;" = type="submit" name="loginBtn" value="Login"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
</html>
```

My code for database.php is:

```
<?php

// intialize variables to hold connection parameters
$username = 'root';
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=register';
$password = 'xxxx';


try{
    // create an instance of the PDO class with the required parameters
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    // set PDO error mode to exception
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // display success message
    // echo "Connected to the register database";

}catch (PDOException $ex){

    // display error message
    echo "Connection unsuccesful. ERROR: ".$ex->getMessage();
}
```

and my code for utilities.php is this:

```
<?php

/**
    * @param $required_fields_array, n array containing the list of all required fields
    * @return array, containing all errors
*/

// start

 function check_empty_fields($required_fields_array){
        // initialize an array to store error messages
        $form_errors = array();

        // loop throgh the required fields array and popular the form error array
        foreach ($required_fields_array as $name_of_field){
            if(!isset($_POST[$name_of_field]) || $_POST[$name_of_field] == NULL){
                $form_errors[] = $name_of_field . "is a required field";

            }

        }

        return $form_errors;
}

/**
    * @param $fields_to_check_length, an array containing the name of fields
    * for which we wnt th check min required length e.g. array('username' => 4, 'email' => 12)
    * @return array, containing all errors
*/

function check_min_length($fields_to_check_length){
    //initialize an array to store error messages
    $form_errors = array();

    foreach($fields_to_check_length as $name_of_field => $minimum_length_required){
        if(strlen(trim($_POST[$name_of_field])) < $minimum_lenth_required){
            $form_errors[] = $name_of_field . " is too short, must be {$minimum_length_required} characters long";

        }
    }
    return $form_errors;
}


/**
    * @param $data, store a key/value pair array where key is the name of the form control
    * in this case 'email' and value is the input entered by the user
    * @return array, containing email error
*/

function check_email($data){
    //initialize an array to store error messages
    $form_errors + array();
    $key = 'email';
    // check if the key email exists in data array
    if(array_key_exists($key, $data)){

        // check if the email field has a value
        if($_POST[$key] != null){

            // remove all illegal characters from email
            $key = filter_var($key, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

            // check if input is a valid email addresss
            if(filter_var($_POST[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
                $form_errors[] = $key . " is not a valid email address";
            }
        }
    }

    return $form_errors;
}

/**
    * @param $form_errors_array, the array holding all
    * errors which we want to loop through
    * @return string, list containing all error messages
*/

function show_errors($form_errors_array){
    $errors = "<p><ul style ='color: red;'>";

    // loop through error array and display all items in a list
    foreach($form_errors_array as $the_error){
        $errors .= "<li> {$the_error} </li>";
    }
    $errors .= "</ul><p>";
    return $errors;
}
```

Lastly, my sessions.php is:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

When I press the login button without entering anything, I get the expected error message. However, if I enter the demo account I made, I still get the same error message.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

- Sianna

A

Comment: What are the _issues_ / errors...?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: When I press the login button without entering anything, I get the expected error message. However, if I enter the demo account I made, I still get the same error message.

Comment: Hi @SiannaZewdie. Could you amend the _exact_ error message you are receiving? This makes it easier to reconstruct the path in your code which leads to that error.

Comment: Hi @acran. What do you mean? What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields you are checking as required contain spaces at the end:

```
$required_fields = array('username ', 'password ');
```

So therefore these names never exist in the posted data. Change that line to:

```
$required_fields = array('username', 'password');
```

And it should work.

UPDATE: I didn't notice before but your form inputs also have the space at the end of the name. Remove the space from there too. When the form is submitted and has those spaces at the end the $_POST contains 'username_' and 'password_'. i.e. PHP is converting the spaces to underscores.

If you added the space just so that the error message had a space then the correct place to add the space would be just before "is a required field" and not in the input names themselves.

Remember to reload the page after making that change.